# Modifying table ejs with addEventListener won't stop

Tags: html, node.js, for-loop, ejs, addeventlistener

I have a table of dynamically generated data with nodejs and have to modify it like an excel in the browser. I have the element that interest me (the first one passed) but also the rest of the whole table which doesn't interest me. How can I make it stop? I've tried e.stopPropagation()

**My generated table, I've only worked with "denomination for the moment**

```
<% for (var i=0; i<nomenclature.length; i++){ %>
            <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a class="bouton" href="/nomenclature/<%= nomenclature[i].idPiece %> ">Ajout bon de commande</a>
                    </td>
                    <td id="idPiece<%=i%>" name="idPiece">
                        <%=nomenclature[i].idPiece %> 
                    </td>
                    <td contenteditable='true' id="denomination<%=i%>" class="denomination1">
                        <%=nomenclature[i].denomination %> 
                    </td>
                    <td contenteditable='true' class="n_piece_plan">
                        <%=nomenclature[i].n_piece_plan %> 
                    </td>
                    <td contenteditable='true'>
                        <%=nomenclature[i].rev %> 
                    </td>
                    <td contenteditable='true'>
                        <%=nomenclature[i].qte %> 
                    </td>
                    <td contenteditable='true'>
                        <%=nomenclature[i].unite %> 
                    </td>
                    <td contenteditable='true'>
                        <%=nomenclature[i].matiere %> 
                    </td>
</tr><script>
My script see below
</script>
            <% } %> 
    </table>
```

**My script in ejs**

```
var all = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
            for (var j=1; j<all.length;j++){
                all[j].addEventListener("input", function(e) {
                    const newData = this.innerHTML;
                    const myID = document.getElementById("idPiece<%=i%>").innerHTML;
                    const myColumn = this.className;
                    const data = {newData, myID, myColumn};
                    const options = {
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: {
                        'Content-Type':'application/json'
                        },
                    body: JSON.stringify(data)
                    };
                    fetch('./nomenclature/inter/modification', options);
                    e.stopPropagation();
                }, false);       
            }
```

**My controller**

```
exports.nomenclatureModification = function(request, response){
    let newData = request.body.newData;
    let myID = request.body.myID;
    newData = newData.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|\s)/gm,"");
    myID = myID.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|\s)/gm,"");
    let myColumn = request.body.myColumn;

    console.log(newData +" ahiiiiii "+ myColumn +" rooooh "+ myID);
    /*
    connection.query('UPDATE nomenclature SET ?? = ? WHERE idPiece = ?;',[myColumn,newData,myID], function(error, resultSQL){
        if (error) throw error;
        else{
            console.log("modif enregistrer en bdd");
        }
    });
    */
    response.redirect('/nomenclature');
}
```

The first element passed thru the console.log is the one I've modified and so my sql query can be made with that one (I can change easily every column). But because my script is nested inside the loop (to obtain idPiece[i] of my changed row) it also prints out the rest which I would like to stop.

**EDIT**: found *a* solution:

1. got the script out of the loop
2. changed my table with a id for each

```
<td contenteditable='true' id="<%=i%>" class="n_piece_plan">
                        <%=nomenclature[i].n_piece_plan %> 
                    </td>
```

3. script change to access that id

```
for (var j=0; j<all.length;j++){
            all[j].addEventListener("input", function(e) {
                const newData = this.innerHTML;
                let stringID = 'idPiece' + this.id;
                const myID = document.getElementById(stringID).innerHTML;
                const myColumn = this.className;
                const data = {newData, myID, myColumn};
                const options = {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                    'Content-Type':'application/json'
                    },
                body: JSON.stringify(data)
                };
                fetch('./nomenclature/inter/modification', options);
                e.stopPropagation();
            }, false);       
        }
```

I can now modify my table in the browser exactly like an Excel table and update that in my db. Performance is ok.